# Problems with the "notes" DropboxAPI example on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

There is a DropboxAPI example: notes on the developers site to get you started on developing using DropboxAPI(s). I followed all the instructions, I copied the libs files you get from the online download and added it as a library, even added it in the grade.build file for compilation, copied the app key and secret key after registration of the app online! I simply can't get it to work, I do not have any compilation errors! Everything seems fine, but it "Stops unexpectedly" every-time I run the thing on my phone. This is what the log shows:

`02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.dropbox.ledger.android.Ledger.newBuilder, referenced from method com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initLedger
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 5500: Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;.newBuilder ()Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger$Builder;
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000e
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/LedgerUrlCallbackImpl; interface 794 'Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/LedgerUrlCallback;'
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/LedgerUrlCallbackImpl;' failed
02-24 00:02:26.607    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1b40 at 0x90 in Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/CoreAccountManager;.initLedger
02-24 00:02:26.617    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager﹕ Prepared cache dir '/data/data/com.dropbox.examples.notes/app_DropboxSyncCache/uq7537992psy7ia'.
02-24 00:02:26.617    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/NativeLib;.nativeLibIsLoaded:()Z
02-24 00:02:26.617    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/NativeLib;
02-24 00:02:26.617    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-24 00:02:26.617    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41627898)
02-24 00:02:26.627    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DropboxSync from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dropbox.examples.notes-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dropbox.examples.notes-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.ensureLoaded(NativeLib.java:70)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:32)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:228)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:141)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:200)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:160)
            at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:107)
            at com.dropbox.examples.notes.NotesAppConfig.getAccountManager(NotesAppConfig.java:15)
            at com.dropbox.examples.notes.NoteListFragment.onAttach(NoteListFragment.java:202)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
            at com.dropbox.examples.notes.NoteListActivity.onCreate(NoteListActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5145)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 00:02:28.997    4741-4741/com.dropbox.examples.notes I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4741 SIG: 9`

This is the site: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android

The examples are in the sdks file(6MB)

Comment: There's really nothing else in the log? If you're still experiencing this issue, feel free to submit your problematic copy of the example app to Dropbox API support so we can try to reproduce and investigate it: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: @Greg I have sent a report! Also I updated the post above.

Comment: @Greg I had the log on a different setting!

Comment: Thanks for the output! That's very helpful. This error generally doesn't indicate an issue with SDK but rather just with the development environment/library addition. Can you check that you've copied across all of the files in the libs/ directory from the API, and refreshed your project in Eclipse before rebuilding? This sort of error might happen if you forgot to copy over the .so files in the subdirectories, or if those files are from a different API version than the .jar file.

Comment: @Greg I did check the libs folder and I have copied all the files, I'm working on Android Studio! and, I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, no luck!

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize you were using Android Studio and not Eclipse. We do have special instructions for Android Studio here under the Eclipse instructions: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android Did you follow those in particular? If so, what version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @Greg Oh my god, I hadn't added the jniLibs folder under main, I am so terrible sorry! Thanks a bunch:)